# What is the preferred base class for Payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, best-practice

I will write a payment module and read some tutorials. All tutorials are using `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc` or `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` to extend from, but both are deprecated.

What ist the preferred class to write a payment method?

Comment: You can read more here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5304.

Comment: I would suggest looking here as well if you have not already. [Magento 2 Sample Payment Gateway Module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these both methods are deprecated. Instead, you should use Magento Payment Gateway.

More details about Magento Payment Gateway components and how to implement new payment integration you can find in [Magento dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html).